# Email and attachments encryption

Tags: security, email

How can I ensure that my email and attachments sent through gmail are encrypted, and can not be accessed by others?

Comment: encrypt text, paste in gmail, send. Else, encrypt, attach, send.

Comment: You can't. How do you define access by others? Access by Google? People sniffing your internet connection? Non-encrypted messages will always be readable to somebody. If you want to guarantee that your message stays encrypted, encrypt it **before** sending it.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like pgp or gpg to encrypt your content before sending- there is a very nice 'encrypt current window' option in pgp for this.

Of course this still doesn't hide the recipient, which may be an issue...

(Also consider migrating to security.stackexchange.com)